# How to disable Japanese-mode input on a UITextField object?

Tags: uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a simple question.
In an iApp in Japanese I have one UITextField object which do not need Japanese input.
Is it possible to disable Japanese-mode input only for this one object.
(That would make the input much easier for the user)

I have already tried:

```
myTextField.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

and it does not work.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITextField has keyboardType property.
When the keyboardType is set to **UIKeyboardTypeDefault**, Japanese keyboard could be shown as a default keyboard.

```
typedef enum {
   UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
   UIKeyboardTypeURL,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
   UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
   UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
   UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,
   UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
} UIKeyboardType;
```

To set keyboadType Programmatically, you can use **setKeyboardType**  as folows:

```
[myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable];
```

The document is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Comment: Yes indeed the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad type is perfect for what I need. Except for the fact that it has no return key, which gives me some other kind of headache. I found some ways to add such a key, on the net. But they don't work though at this point. I will have to dig more into this issue.